# Wso2 cant write groups in external LDAP

Tags: soap, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am configuring Wso2 with a read write external LDAP.
I am using the SOAP Api provided by Wso2 for managing users n groups.

However when trying to add a user to an internal group everything works fine but when i try to add a user to an external LDAP group i get that the role does not exist. Which is weird cause i can see the roles in Wso2. I even can i add a user to an external group from there but after it is added its not showed as added even it is actually added in the LDAP.

This is the ldap connection configuration

```
<UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager">
            <Property name="TenantManager">org.wso2.carbon.user.core.tenant.CommonHybridLDAPTenantManager</Property>
            <Property name="ConnectionURL">ldaps://some-url:636</Property>
            <Property name="ConnectionName">cn=admin,ou=adminGroups,dc=userstore,dc=gk</Property>
            <Property name="ConnectionPassword">someAdminPass</Property>
            <Property name="AnonymousBind">false</Property>
            <Property name="UserSearchBase">ou=users,dc=userstore,dc=gk</Property>
            <Property name="UserEntryObjectClass">inetOrgPerson</Property>
            <Property name="UserNameAttribute">uid</Property>
            <Property name="UserNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=?))</Property>
            <Property name="UserNameListFilter">(objectClass=posixAccount)</Property>
            <Property name="DisplayNameAttribute"/>
            <Property name="ReadGroups">true</Property>
            <Property name="WriteGroups">true</Property>
            <Property name="GroupSearchBase">ou=groups,dc=userstore,dc=gk</Property>
            <Property name="GroupEntryObjectClass">posixGroup</Property>
            <Property name="GroupNameAttribute">cn</Property>
            <Property name="GroupNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=posixGroup)(cn=?))</Property>
            <Property name="GroupNameListFilter">(objectClass=posixGroup)</Property>
            <Property name="MembershipAttribute">memberOf</Property>
            <Property name="BackLinksEnabled">false</Property>
            <Property name="UsernameJavaRegEx">someregex stuff</Property>
            <Property name="UsernameJavaScriptRegEx">someregex stuff</Property>
            <Property name="UsernameJavaRegExViolationErrorMsg">Username pattern policy violated</Property>
            <Property name="PasswordJavaRegEx">someregex stuff</Property>
            <Property name="PasswordJavaScriptRegEx">someregex stuff</Property>
            <Property name="PasswordJavaRegExViolationErrorMsg">Password length should be within 5 to 30 characters</Property>
            <Property name="RolenameJavaRegEx">someregex stuff</Property>
            <Property name="RolenameJavaScriptRegEx">someregex stuff</Property>
            <Property name="SCIMEnabled">true</Property>
            <Property name="IsBulkImportSupported">false</Property>
            <Property name="EmptyRolesAllowed">true</Property>
            <Property name="PasswordHashMethod">PLAIN_TEXT</Property>
            <Property name="MultiAttributeSeparator">,</Property>
            <Property name="MaxUserNameListLength">100</Property>
            <Property name="MaxRoleNameListLength">100</Property>
            <Property name="kdcEnabled">false</Property>
            <Property name="defaultRealmName">WSO2.ORG</Property>
            <Property name="UserRolesCacheEnabled">true</Property>
            <Property name="ConnectionPoolingEnabled">false</Property>
            <Property name="LDAPConnectionTimeout">5000</Property>
            <Property name="ReadTimeout"/>
            <Property name="RetryAttempts"/>
        </UserStoreManager>
```

I am using SoapUi to make this call having this request body

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ser="http://service.ws.um.carbon.wso2.org">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <ser:updateRoleListOfUser>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ser:userName>username</ser:userName>
         <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
         <ser:deletedRoles>?</ser:deletedRoles>
         <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
         <ser:newRoles>Users</ser:newRoles>
      </ser:updateRoleListOfUser>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Seems that some configuration has gone wrong.Is there some special configuration needed to to that ?

Comment: can you post your ldap config in wso2 and the request you used in ws call?

Comment: hope the update helps.Thanks!!!

Comment: wso2 tool and endpoint url?

Comment: I try with WSO2 IS 5.3.0: get the authentication cookie with the https://localhost:9443/services/AuthenticationAdmin.AuthenticationAdminHttpsSoap11Endpoint/ service and the operation login and calling the https://localhost:9443/services/RemoteUserStoreManagerService.RemoteUserStoreManagerServiceHttpsSoap11Endpoint/ service with the operation updateRoleListOfUser and setting the cookie authetication header...

Answer (score 0):

This was a silly mistake. I am passing `<ser:deletedRoles>?</ser:deletedRoles>` and that is what actually throws the error saying that group does not exist.

About the part that i say

> after it is added its not showed as added even it is actually added in
>   the LDAP

This has to do with a different setup that i use in my LDAP server. I have created an additional [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45757267/wso2-use-memberuid-on-external-ldap-for-groups) for this configuration issue.