# Wso2 use memberUid on external LDAP for groups

Tags: configuration, ldap, wso2, openldap, wso2-identity-server

I have connected Wso2 with an external LDAP. So, i want to handle the LDAP groups. However in Wso2 [doc](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Configuring+a+Read-write+LDAP+User+Store) it states to use :

- `groupOfNames` as our `objectClass` and
- `member` as our `MembershipAttribute`

However my current LDAP server is not like that. This means that i use

- `PosixGroup` as my `objectClass` and
- `memberUid` for my `MembershipAttribute`

This leads me to the point that , when i add a user to a group, then Wso2 goes and puts this value `uid=b1,ou=users,dc=transip,dc=nl` inside `memberUid`. This is not compatible with my set up. What i need is Wso2 to just put the user's `uid` in the `memberUid` field and then the entry will be compatible with the rest of my setup.

How can i configure Wso2 to pass the `uid` when adding a user to a group instead of passing `dn` (Distinguished Name).

Answer (score 0):

According to JIRA [1], this issue has been already fixed in WSO2 IS 5.1.0. According to the JIRA to get your setup working you need to configure GroupObjectClass as "PosixGroup" and MembershipAttribute as "memberUid" in the UserStoreManager configuration relevant to your UserStore.

[1] https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-3400

Comment: I am using these values, `posixGroup` for `objectClass` and `memberUid` for `MembershipAttribute` but still wso2 writes the `dn` value in the `memberUid` field. In the pull request of the fix [link](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-kernel/pull/290) says this fix is for `readOnlyLDAPUserStore` . Could it be that this was fixed only for the read only ??

Comment: So searching on that pull request... we have these 2 files
[ReadOnly](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-kernel/blob/2162f91fced0bca79272092be68447237aa6e3b5/core/org.wso2.carbon.user.core/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/user/core/ldap/ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.java) and
[ReadWrite](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-kernel/blob/2162f91fced0bca79272092be68447237aa6e3b5/core/org.wso2.carbon.user.core/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/user/core/ldap/ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.java)
So the `memberUid` support was added in the ReadOnly but not in the ReadWrite

Comment: However these files exist up to 4.5.x. After 5.0.x the structure is changed...not sure where this logic is located on 5.3.x

Answer (score 0):

The same question has posted in https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-6295 as well. In order to achieve this its need to write custom user store manager, changing member attribute to add only uid, rather full DN.